# DataTables - How can I attach an id, class and events to added cells in DataTables?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I need to add an id, class and an event to newly added cells in DataTables while using the below code. How can I accomplish that?

```
var rtn = oTable.fnAddData(['Cell1Value', 'Cell2Value', 'Cell3Value']);
```

I am trying to fire a javaScript function upon clicking on this newly added cell[s].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bit clunky, but you can achieve what your looking for by doing something like this.

[***Created a fiddle here***](http://jsfiddle.net/FG8FS/)

**HTML**

```
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Rendering engine</th>
                <th>Browser</th>
                <th>Platform(s)</th>
                <th>Engine version</th>
                <th>CSS grade</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="odd gradeX">
                <td>Trident</td>
                <td>Internet
                     Explorer 4.0</td>
                <td>Win 95+</td>
                <td class="center"> 4</td>
                <td class="center">X</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="even gradeC">
                <td>Trident</td>
                <td>Internet
                     Explorer 5.0</td>
                <td>Win 95+</td>
                <td class="center">5</td>
                <td class="center">C</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="odd gradeA">
                <td>Trident</td>
                <td>Internet
                     Explorer 5.5</td>
                <td>Win 95+</td>
                <td class="center">5.5</td>
                <td class="center">A</td>
            </tr>
      </tbody>  
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Rendering engine</th>
                <th>Browser</th>
                <th>Platform(s)</th>
                <th>Engine version</th>
                <th>CSS grade</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
<button id="addnewrow">Add New Row</button>
```

**JS**

```
$('#addnewrow').click(function(){
//add row
  var newRow = $('#example').dataTable().fnAddData( [
   "1",
    "2",
    "3",
    "4",
     "5"]
  );

  //change cell attributes
  var oSettings = dataTable.fnSettings();
var nTr = oSettings.aoData[ newRow[0] ].nTr;
$('td', nTr)[0].setAttribute( 'id', 'newid1' );
$('td', nTr)[1].setAttribute( 'id', 'newid2' );
$('td', nTr)[2].setAttribute( 'id', 'newid3' );
$('td', nTr)[3].setAttribute( 'id', 'newid4' );
$('td', nTr)[4].setAttribute( 'id', 'newid5' );

});
```

Then you can simply delegate the click of your new id or class with something like this

```
$('table').delegate('#newid1','click', function(){
 alert('clicked on new cell 1') 
})
```

[Here is the reference](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/4342/setting-tr-id-after-using-fnadddata-solved/p1)

Comment: Thanks. I am following your code example, but modified it a little bit to suit my needs.

var rtn = oTable.fnAddData(['Cell1Value', 'Cell2Value', 'Cell3Value']);

var oTRAdded = oTable.fnGetNodes(rtn);

newCell = $('td:eq(0)', oTRAdded);

newCell.id = 'newId';

$(newCell).on('click', function (e) { alert('blah'); }